# Pre loaded database on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I developing an app that is read-only. The data has relationships, so I cannot just use a plist or something similar.

Questions:

- Should I use Core Data for such a requirement?
- If so, how would I enter the data and then release the app with that data?
- How would I make it so that the app doesn't need to re-populate a DB every time it loads?
- Is there a way to create a Core Data model using sql commands with sqlite (i.e. insert into, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my short experience with the iPhone, you have two options.

1. Write a data import function and run it on the first application launch.
2. Use solution 1, but build the initial sqllite file in the simulator, and then on first application launch, copy it into the app's documents directory.

From past experience, option 2 is much quicker for user experience, and the preferred solution.

Answer (score 4):

You may use an SQLite database to accomplish this.

1. Create the model in your iOS app.
2. Create and populate the database in a Mac OSX utility command-line app
3. Copy the sqlite file into your iOS app and link it with some code

Work through these two tutorials, line by line, and afterward you will have a good enough understanding (and code sample) to complete this task in your own app.

- [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)
- [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: How To Preload and Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.....

So is this the only/best way to achieve the pre loaded db? Would apps such as trivial pursuit use such methods for example (obviously this would be guess work, but in your opinion)??

Many thanks

Jules

Comment: +1 Everything that ships with the app has to be in the app bundle. You can easily include a pre-populated database but it will always be read only. Your only other option is to include all the data in an XML and then generate the DB in the app's directories upon first launch. User's usually don't like the latter because it bogs their shiny new app.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, it seems a pre populated sqlite db is the more efficient way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utility project that imports the app's data model and use throwaway code n that project to populate the Core Data DB. Once the DB is populated, simply copy the actual file to the app project's resources folder and then when you set up your persistent store, use NSBundle to return the path to the DB file within the built app.

And you're done.